# Chrome now blocking all jsonp requests from https to http?

Tags: security, google-chrome, https, jsonp, securitydomain

At some point recently Chrome has stopped showing data loaded via jsonp with the error

[blocked] The page at https://user.example.com/category/12345 ran insecure content from http://livedata.example.com/Data.svc/jsonp/GetData?category=12345&callback=_jsp&_1346417951424=.

It still works fine on all other browsers, and has been confirmed on several different computers running Chrome.

The only mention I've seen of this problem before is when the page was served from one of Google's own domains (a security feature for Google Apps I guess?), is this something that has been enabled on all domains now in a recent version of Chrome?

Ideally we don't want to have to enable https on our livedata subdomain because of the extra server load it would cause, the data is all publicly available so there's no pressing need to encrypt it.

Answer (score 19):

It definitely should block it - it's insecure and breaks the promise of HTTPS.

A JSONP resource fetch is done by creating a `<script>` resource pointing at the target. That means the target server can run any JavaScript it likes on the including page, and hence any man-in-the-middle can inject arbitrary script into a supposedly-HTTPS-protected page (eg adding a keylogger, or completely replacing the page content). An HTTPS page with a `<script>` coming from HTTP is no more secure than a plain HTTP page.

You will need to provide an HTTPS version of your data feed, if you want HTTPS pages to be able to access it. Otherwise browsers should, at the very least, produce warnings. Chrome now defaulting to block doesn't change the nature of the problem, it's just giving you the extra push you need to fix it properly.

Comment: Good point, of course this all stems from browsers blocking ajax xml calls across domains which would be a lot more secure as no chance to inject javascript, at least they're starting to fix /that/ problem with HTML5

Comment: The security point is good, but what happens when you are tapping into 3rd party services that do not offer CORS nor HTTPS?

Comment: @Stefano: there is no way for that to be made secure. Hopefully the block will persuade more 3rd-party services to offer HTTPS versions of their APIs.

Comment: @bobince I agree, as a lazy developer I was just hoping for some big confirmation dialog to smooth the transition; but I fully understand that most people would just click without undestanding what's going on... and that would indeed still break the service in half the cases!

Comment: @bobince You mention keyloggers and others as an issue. How would using an https resource help in that regards? You would still be able to do all those things you just mentioned, it is just being done over a secure channel. I mean if you include an https script, for instance jQuery, how can you be sure jQuery is not logging your strokes, and relaying on info? If security is a concern, then all third party scripts should be forbidden over a so called "secure" site. I am not sure https qualifies for that. Perhaps a third party script is not allowed to add ...

Comment: ... css, scripts, images and jsonp requests on its own? I doubt that is the case in todays browsers. I don't think they keep track of how an image or script and whatnot was inserted into the dom tree... am I wrong?

Comment: @MoJS: The webmaster of the top-level page is assumed to have responsibility for ensuring that only good content is included. There is a trust relationship between the user and the webmaster, and the webmaster and the third party. Whilst I would agree that too many sites include third-party script without properly considering the consequences (resulting in exploits over ad networks etc), it's a consistent approach to trust the third-party webmaster's judgement over who he trusts.

Comment: However it is not consistent to claim a page is secure if the resources might be coming from random network interlopers that are trusted by neither the user nor the webmaster, as is the case when resources are being served from non-HTTPS addresses.

Comment: Also, serving content via HTTPS means the data is encrypted, rendering Man-In-The-Middle attacks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) useless. The end user browsing to an HTTPS page can rest assure any data passed back and forth is encrypted (as the key icon shows as well), only if ALL requests must be HTTPS.

Answer (score 7):

`<script src="//domain.com/script.js"></script>` solves the problem if remote server allows HTTPS... // will automatically set protocol to https if site is accessed by https.