# Error: The page at 'index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint

Tags: javascript, html

I deployed a website that contained an API that was not working.

In console, it shows some errors. but the site was working properly on my localhost.

Error:
`Mixed Content: The page at 'index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint ---"URL". This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make XMLHttpRequest work over HTTPS on google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607218/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-work-over-https-on-google-chrome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that you accessed your website using `HTTPS`, but when you `XMLHttpRequest`, you're using `HTTP` in that code. It would be helpful to see that code. If you're using `XMLHttpRequest` like this: `http://example.com/`, change it to: `https://example.com/`. This error means you need to use all `HTTPS` or all `HTTP`.

Edit: According to [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607218/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-work-over-https-on-google-chrome), you should actually leave out the `http`/`https` completely:
`//example.com/`

Comment: Please mark it as accepted answer then! :)

Comment: Add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` to the html file, this would solve the issue.

You can read more on [Mozilla Develop Doc][1]


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests